# NSURL escaped characters don't work

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I'm having a problem with creating an NSURL object using an URL string which looks like this:

"... fexp=935648%2C945012%2C901066%2C91 ..." and so on (it's just a part - the complete URL is very long).

The URL contains many percentage escaped characters (%2C). I am absolutely not able to create an NSURL object with this URL (the URL itself is correct, as I can open it using a browser). The call to

```
[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
```

returns NIL.

As soon as I modify the url by calling

```
[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

I receive a valid NSURL object.

Problem is: this "valid" NSURL object contains an invalid URL which looks like this:

"... fexp=935648%252C945012%252C901066%225C91 ..."

As you can see the initial percent escaped character (%2C) has been escaped again (%252C) which results in an URL which cannot be opened (tried it using a browser again).

The original URL is generated by an external tool so I don't have any influence on its creation mechanism.

Does anybody have a clue what might be wrong?

Comment: If you call `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` before creating your NSURL, does it work? `[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]];`

Comment: i thing the url is already been encoded... wht are u encoding again.. try Michaels comment

Comment: Weird... just removing percent encoded characters does not work. But first removing those characters and re-adding them seems to work... Perhaps there was something coded within the URL I did not see (I already tried `[url stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]`.

Comment: yes... u have to remove the encoding and then you again have to encode the Url will work... please post your answer so that it might be helpful to others

Answer (score 4):

To me it seems a little bit strange but the following seems to work:

```
[url stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
```

Thanks for the hints.